# Any possible way to change the color / background color of the <SpeedDial/> component of Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, css-in-js

When I tried to change the color of the  component it doesn't change, still having the mui primary color.

I tried to change the color like this:
`<SpeedDial ariaLabel="SpeedDial" icon={<SpeedDialIcon />} sx={{ color: green[500],}} >`

And the background color like this:
`<SpeedDial ariaLabel="SpeedDial" icon={<SpeedDialIcon />} sx={{ backgroundColor: green[500],}} >`
But changing the background color like this changes the whole bg area which includes the floating icons.